# Azure Website failed to provision

Tags: provisioning, azure-web-app-service

I got a question, and azure support site, redirects me to stackoverflow, so I hope some guys are able to help wit my problem. I recently removed a azurewebsites site. After that I wanted to readd the azurewebsites site. But it returned the message 'Failed to provision'. i guess my previous removal resolved in a faulted state or something because this website is not on my management portal anymore and i am not able to create. I retried a few times the last few days. Seems the site is still faulted...

Hope somebody can help me out? Azure team?

Comment: So you are trying to create a website with the same name as before? Are there any error details in the portal directly after executing the operation or in the *management services/operation logs*?

Comment: Hi i created the website with the same name as before, and get the message 'Failed to provision'. When i tried it with a different name it worked like normal. It also wont appear in the service logs...

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a591513c-6451-4f20-9609-2bbafb17a3a2/fixing-provisioning-failed-errors-in-azure-websites?forum=windowsa) is one of the solutions which worked for me